# What does the prefix in Apple's sample apple-app-site-association appID refer to

Tags: app-store, deep-linking

Does anyone know what the prefix `ABCDE12345` in front of the app ID refers to in [Apple's sample apple-app-site-association snippet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains)?

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app", "ABCDE12345.com.example.app2" ],
             "components": [
               {
                  "#": "no_universal_links",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose fragment equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/buy/*",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /buy/"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/help/website/*",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/website/ and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/help/*",
                  "?": { "articleNumber": "????" },
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/ and which has a query item with name 'articleNumber' and a value of exactly 4 characters"
               }
             ]
           }
       ]
   },
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app" ]
   },
    "appclips": {
        "apps": ["ABCED12345.com.example.MyApp.Clip"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the TEAM ID in App Store connect, this app is associated with